# How to retain conditional formatting on historical and new cells when inserting new column in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a macro that inserts a new column each week to a spread sheet.  I have conditional formatting that indicates if cell H2 less than B2, then format font red.  I need this retained for all historical columns as well as the newly inserted column each week.  How do I do this?

Comment: The new column is being added to the left of column H.  Column H is week 1 of 2016, I add new column,  Column H is now week 2 of 2016 and week 1 of 2016 is now column I.  I need both columns conditionally formatted based on whether each individual column is less than the value in column B.  This will continue each wee.  I hope this helps to clarify my sisue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you mean with *retain*, you need to put `$` signs in front of the columns/rows that you do *not* want to change.

for example, if you write `$H2<$B2`, it is *absolute*, and it will always compare the columns H and B, even if they contain something different after your insertion. If you use `H2<B2`, both are *relative*, and if you insert for example a column at F, the formula will adjust itself to `I2<B2` - it will apply to the same content, not the same place.

Put a `$` at each row and/or column that you want to *hold*, and *no* `$` at each row and/or column that you want to *flow* with the insertion. Note that they can be mixed freely, like `H$2<$B2` or whatever.

Comment: There would be a lot less options if the OP had stated if newly added columns where right of column H or not. If they are, nothing changes. If they are between column H and B, only column H changes and needs to the absolute ($H). Third case is if columns are added left of column B.